# Igor Pro, how to create a text wave that concatenates multiple input text waves with no duplicates

Tags: igor

I have 11 different text waves with the identified molecular formulas from different samples. I need to create a single "master" text wave with ALL the formulas identified in all samples WITHOUT ANY DUPLICATES.

Answer (score 0):

In Igor 7+ you can do this with the `FindDuplicates` command.

The steps needed are:

```
// concatenate 11 different text waves
// make a string of semicolon separated wavenames that you'd like to combine e.g.
String wList = WaveList("textw*",";","")
// and do
Concatenate/O/NP=0 wList, longTextWave
// an alternative is to type them all out
Concatenate/O/NP=0 textw0,textw1, ... textw11, longTextWave
// longTextWave will be a long 1D text wave (/NP=0 does this job)
// get unique formulas
FindDuplicates/O/RT=uniqueTextWave longTextWave
```

Unique formulas are in uniqueTextWave